# Side by side divs with label in input fields

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to modify the css to insert label in input field. I want them to be one, is it possible ? Also I should keep the side by side aspect for the divs. I tried the flex method to keep the divs side by side, but the label and input field are two separate elements rather than a single element. As you can see from the example code, the label is red while the input field does not undergo the same change.

```js
calculate = function() {
  var carb = document.getElementById('carb').value;
  var pro = document.getElementById('pro').value;
  var fat = document.getElementById('fat').value;

  //Kcal Totali
  var kcaltot = (4 * carb) + (4 * pro) + (9 * fat);
  document.getElementById('kcaltot').value = kcaltot.toLocaleString('it-IT', {
    maximumFractionDigits: 0
  }) + " Kcal/day";

  //Kcal Macro
  var kcal_carb = (carb * 4);
  document.getElementById('kcal_carb').value = kcal_carb.toLocaleString('it-IT', {
    maximumFractionDigits: 0
  }) + " Kcal";

  var kcal_pro = (pro * 4);
  document.getElementById('kcal_pro').value = kcal_pro.toLocaleString('it-IT', {
    maximumFractionDigits: 0
  }) + " Kcal";

  var kcal_fat = (fat * 9);
  document.getElementById('kcal_fat').value = kcal_fat.toLocaleString('it-IT', {
    maximumFractionDigits: 0
  }) + " Kcal";

  //Kcal Percentage
  var p_carb = (carb * 4) / (kcaltot) * 100;
  document.getElementById('p_carb').value = p_carb.toLocaleString('it-IT', {
    maximumFractionDigits: 0
  }) + " %";

  var p_pro = (pro * 4) / (kcaltot) * 100;
  document.getElementById('p_pro').value = p_pro.toLocaleString('it-IT', {
    maximumFractionDigits: 0
  }) + " %";

  var p_fat = (fat * 9) / (kcaltot) * 100;
  document.getElementById('p_fat').value = p_fat.toLocaleString('it-IT', {
    maximumFractionDigits: 0
  }) + " %";
}
```

```css
.container_macros {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
}

.container_macros>div {
  flex: 1;
  outline: none;
}

.m_field {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  outline: none !important;
}

.container_macros.grams input {
  border: none;
  text-align:
}

.container_macros.grams label {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: roboto;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #5F6A7C;
}

.kcal_res {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.kcal_total label {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: titillium web;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #5F6A7C;
}

.kcal_total input {
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  font-family: titillium web;
  background: #f9fafd;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.kcal_total input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  background: #f9fafd;
}
```

```html
<!---Grams_input--->
<div class="container_macros grams">
  <label>prprpr</label>
  <input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="m_field" maxlength="3" id="carb" name "pro" placeholder="150g" form="macro" onchange="calculate()" required/>


  <label>prprpr</label>
  <input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="m_field" maxlength="3" id="pro" name "pro" placeholder="150g" form="macro" onchange="calculate()" required/>

  <label>prprpr</label>
  <input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="m_field" maxlength="3" id="fat" name "pro" placeholder="150g" form="macro" onchange="calculate()" required/>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/snake93/zcdq2vx9/94/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're asking, but if you want the labels and inputs to both turn red, you can either wrap your inputs with the `<label>` tags.

Or alternatively wrap both the `<label>` and `<input />` tags with divs, and apply your styling to the parent `<div>`.

e.g.

```
<label>prprpr
    <input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" type="number" class="m_field" maxlength="3" id="carb" name"pro" placeholder="150g" form="macro" onchange="calculate()" required />
</label>
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/v3gp20y5/